# Using variable in excel formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula in my VBA code in which I  would like to embed a variable. I defined an integer but am unsure how to add it to my formula.

```
 Dim Formula as Variant
 Dim Stability as Integer
 Stability = 0.5
 Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(range("C:C"), range("C:C"), ">=10", range("C:C"), "<=15", range("F:F"), "<=Stability")
```

At the end of the formula I want to include my Stability variable. What is the correct syntax for doing so?

Comment: May i ask the purpose of your code? why don't you just construct the formula and stick it to the cell value so excel will calculate for you? like .range("A2).Formula = "=Average('C:C')" ?

Comment: Note that an `Integer` is a, we'll, _integer_, and cannot hold a floating point value.  Use `Double` instead.

Comment: I tried declaring it as a double but it still errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Formula = ..., "<=" & Stability)
```

Comment: I get an error when doing that. "Unable to get the AverageIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: @MalusPuer make sure you understand how [**=AVERAGEIFS**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx) works

Comment: The code works when I have .5 where stability is in the formula. It just wont let me put a variable there